# Nuwe Score Charts Framework not able to load in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart

I am using following library.

https://github.com/nuwehq/nuwe-charts-ios/wiki

And I created bridging header due to library is in Objective-C language. Everything set up is fine, but, while I am trying to load into tableviewcell, its not loading . Even the framework delegate methods are calling, but not able to load the graph.

My code in TableviewCellforrowatindexpath delegate method

```
cell?.lineChartBar.frame = (cell?.lineChartBar.frame)!
cell?.lineChartBar.barDataSource = self as NUBarChartDataSource
cell?.lineChartBar.barDelegate = self as NUBarChartDelegate
cell?.lineChartBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 56/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
cell?.lineChartBar.reloadDial(withAnimation: false)
cell?.lineChartBar.isHidden = false
```

But, I am not able to find while its not loading. Can anyone suggest me how to load that graph in tableviewcell, if anyone already using this library. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your demo project?

Comment: You can download by that above link in query zip file